# Issue to push static resource (single files and zip) using SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, static-resources, salesforcedx-cli

have any of you faced issues to push static resources to scratch orgs using SFDX v46.8.0?

Asking because I faced this issue and had to revert back salesforcedx plugin to 46.6.0.

```
path\singleFile.resource-meta.xml   Required field is missing: content
path\zipFile.resource-meta.xml      The specified Static Resource is not a valid zip file
```

Note: the zipFile is uncompressed locally.

Looking at [release notes](https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html) don't see any changing around this area.

Comment: You shouldn't be using ZIP files at all. The CLI is supposed to zip/unzip as you push/pull/deploy/retrieve.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, you are correct, I forgot to mention that: the static resource is a zip but the content on local folder is uncompressed as usual. Makes sense?

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue with v46.9.0, so reverting it back to v46.6.0, again. Will file a bug on forcedotcom/cli-packages project to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to symbolic links and is fixed in [SFDX v46.15.3](https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html):

> FIX: On macOS, the temporary zip file created when running
>   force:source:push, force:source:deploy, or force:mdapi:deploy once
>   again contains files that are symbolically linked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by uploading the static resources as a zip file to salesforce and after retrieving them to my project