# SFDX - file symbolic link error

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

File Symbolic links are no longer working, at least they are not when using any version newer than salesforce-cli v46.6.0.

Unexpected errors are presented when pushing code to scratch orgs (sfdx force:source:push).
The push/deployment process fails and throws many different errors:

- In field: page - no ApexPage named `CLASS` found
- The specified Static Resource is not a valid zip file
- Required field is missing: content
- Component `c:COMPONENT_NAME` does not exist

It turned out that the missing files were symbolic links, so it started working again after downgrading to Salesforce DX 46.6.0.

Note that 46.7.0 and 46.8.0 were not released (https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html)

If you're facing the errors weird/unexpected error above, then you can execute the command below to fix it temporarily.

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@46.6.0
```

Does anyone know the root cause or a better way to fix it?

P.S.: Salesforce has accepted this as a bug and now there is a public Known Issue. Please access the link below and click on "This Issue Affects me" if that's the case.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A0000003ebB

Comment: What OS? I'd submit an issue to the [CLI issues repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasTaylor for asking that. It's Mac OS, I've posted a bug there.

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/152

Comment: Also faced a similar issue that I asked: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272155/issue-to-push-static-resource-single-files-and-zip-using-sfdx.
Reported in forcedotcom: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli-packages/issues/90

Comment: Also a problem on Linux. I'm getting a lot of "Must specify both the source file & the metadata file" etc.

Comment: I've executed some extra tests today and I noticed that this bug affects only Symbolic links related to files, NOT folders.
I've presented it to Salesforce support team today, hopefully they will come up with a solution soon.

Comment: Salesforce Support Team has finally accepted this as a bug. 
See below their answer:
"As informed we have reached to our R&D team and they identified this behavior as a BUG at our end. As of now there is no scheduled build for the BUG...".

Comment: I've asked Salesforce to create a public Known Issue. So, please access the link below and click on "This Issue Affects me".
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A0000003ebB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by Salesforce on version 46.15.3 (September 19, 2019).
To install latest version, you should execute the following command:

`sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest`

**Release notes:**

"FIX: On macOS, the temporary zip file created when running force:source:push, force:source:deploy, or force:mdapi:deploy once again contains files that are symbolically linked."

**Source:** https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html